# Ranking Rows in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to create a RANK number as below?

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated field and use the rank function.

1. Create calculated field(Analysis->Create Calculated Field
2. Name the calculation field(going to call it "rank")
3. In the body of the calc field call the rank function, something like this

   ```
   rank(SUM([Number of Records]))
   ```

Here I am ranking on the number of records.

4. Select okay and pull your new calc field on to the view in question.

Comment: But `rank` works as `table calculation` only and therefore needs a context every time!